# Pandas: How to clean unknown values from a dataframe using groupby, diff and map functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe that contains car tire change data which is part of a larger dataset. The dataframe consists of vehicle mileage and tire mileage like so:

```
    Plate   Make    Type    Car_Miles   Tire_Miles  Change
0   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 387         387         Yes
1   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 15698       15311       No
2   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 25083       9385        No
3   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 37229       36842       Yes
4   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 50971       13742       No
5   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 85445       48216       Unknown
6   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 105870      20425       No
7   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 120454      14584       No
8   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 135878      50433       Unknown
9   DEF-456 Honda   Sport   507         507         Yes
10  DEF-456 Honda   Sport   18796       18289       No
11  DEF-456 Honda   Sport   22879       22372       Unknown
12  DEF-456 Honda   Sport   38674       15795       Unknown
13  DEF-456 Honda   Sport   48678       25799       Unknown
14  DEF-456 Honda   Sport   55879       7201        No
15  DEF-456 Honda   Sport   65321       16643       Yes
16  DEF-456 Honda   Sport   78526       13205       No
```

I am trying to use the entries in the tire change column to calculate/verify the tire mileage. To elaborate: For a row where tire change column says "Yes", tire miles are calculated by subtracting the car miles with the previous row that has "Yes" in the change column. If the change column says "No" then the tire miles are simply subtracted with that from the previous row (regardless of whether the previous row has change entries of "Yes" or "No"). However when I encounter "Unknown" entries in the change column, it throws off my code and give me bogus results like in the fourth last row where calculated tire miles = 1000.4:

```
    Plate   Make    Type    Car_Miles   Tire_Miles  Change  Calculated_Tire_Miles
0   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 387         387         Yes     NaN
1   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 15698       15311       No      15311.0
2   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 25083       9385        No      9385.0
3   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 37229       36842       Yes     36842.0
4   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 50971       13742       No      13742.0
5   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 85445       48216       Unknown 48216.0
6   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 105870      20425       No      20425.0
7   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 120454      14584       No      14584.0
8   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 135878      50433       Unknown 50433.0
9   DEF-456 Honda   Sport   507         507         Yes     NaN
10  DEF-456 Honda   Sport   18796       18289       No      18289.0
11  DEF-456 Honda   Sport   22879       22372       Unknown 22372.0
12  DEF-456 Honda   Sport   38674       15795       Unknown 15795.0
13  DEF-456 Honda   Sport   48678       25799       Unknown 10004.0
14  DEF-456 Honda   Sport   55879       7201        No      7201.0
15  DEF-456 Honda   Sport   65321       16643       Yes     16643.0
16  DEF-456 Honda   Sport   78526       13205       No      13205.0
```

Instead of throwing those values out I am trying to clean the change column such that I achieve the desired result:

```
    Plate   Make    Type    Car_Miles   Tire_Miles  Change  Corrected_Change
0   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 387         387         Yes     Yes
1   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 15698       15311       No      No
2   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 25083       9385        No      No
3   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 37229       36842       Yes     Yes
4   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 50971       13742       No      No
5   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 85445       48216       Unknown Yes
6   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 105870      20425       No      No
7   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 120454      14584       No      No
8   ABC-123 Toyota  Comfort 135878      50433       Unknown Yes
9   DEF-456 Honda   Sport   507         507         Yes     Yes
10  DEF-456 Honda   Sport   18796       18289       No      No
11  DEF-456 Honda   Sport   22879       22372       Unknown Yes
12  DEF-456 Honda   Sport   38674       15795       Unknown No
13  DEF-456 Honda   Sport   48678       25799       Unknown Yes
14  DEF-456 Honda   Sport   55879       7201        No      No
15  DEF-456 Honda   Sport   65321       16643       Yes     Yes
16  DEF-456 Honda   Sport   78526       13205       No      No
```

I am new to python and struggling to develop the correct logic. I know that this may/may not require using an if-else condition or a for loop. I would appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction. Here is a part of the code I am using to calculate the tire miles:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Stack_stuff.csv')
m = df.Change.map(dict(Yes=1, No=0)).astype(bool)
df.insert(6, 'Calculated_Tire_Miles', df.groupby(['Plate','Make','Type'])['Car_Miles'].diff().mask(m, df['Car_Miles'].where(m.astype(bool)).ffill().diff()))
df.loc[~(df['Calculated_Tire_Miles'] > 0), 'Calculated_Tire_Miles']=np.nan
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic how to replace Unknown by yes or no?

Comment: One thing to notice is that the value "Unknown" is a string. is it something expected or did you just randomly add it as a dummy value? in real time would we be expecting a nan value instead?

Comment: @Corralien Thanks for pointing that out. It seems I left out that explanation. The logic to replace the "Unknown" by "Yes" or "No" depends on whether the calculated_tire_mile values line up with given tire_mile values. Considering row 13, the calculated_tire_mile value of 10004 does not line up with the given value of 25799. Only when subtracted with row 11, we get the correct calculated value. Hope I was able to clarify this.

Comment: @kush_shah That's a good question. This dataframe is generated via a left join of two separate dataframes. The dataframe which has the Change column is entered through a manual process so it is subject to data quality issues. The only part I omitted was the License plate numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
df['Corrected_Change'] = np.where(df.groupby('Plate')['Car_Miles'].diff()
                                    .sub(df['Tire_Miles']).ne(0),
                                  'Yes', 'No')
```

Output:

```
      Plate    Make     Type  Car_Miles  Tire_Miles   Change Corrected_Change
0   ABC-123  Toyota  Comfort        387         387      Yes              Yes
1   ABC-123  Toyota  Comfort      15698       15311       No               No
2   ABC-123  Toyota  Comfort      25083        9385       No               No
3   ABC-123  Toyota  Comfort      37229       36842      Yes              Yes
4   ABC-123  Toyota  Comfort      50971       13742       No               No
5   ABC-123  Toyota  Comfort      85445       48216  Unknown              Yes
6   ABC-123  Toyota  Comfort     105870       20425       No               No
7   ABC-123  Toyota  Comfort     120454       14584       No               No
8   ABC-123  Toyota  Comfort     135878       50433  Unknown              Yes
9   DEF-456   Honda    Sport        507         507      Yes              Yes
10  DEF-456   Honda    Sport      18796       18289       No               No
11  DEF-456   Honda    Sport      22879       22372  Unknown              Yes
12  DEF-456   Honda    Sport      38674       15795  Unknown               No
13  DEF-456   Honda    Sport      48678       25799  Unknown              Yes
14  DEF-456   Honda    Sport      55879        7201       No               No
15  DEF-456   Honda    Sport      65321       16643      Yes              Yes
16  DEF-456   Honda    Sport      78526       13205       No               No
```

If you want to recalculate the Tire_Miles:

```
m = df['Corrected_Change'].eq('Yes')
df['Calculated_Tire_Miles'] = (
 df.groupby(['Plate', m.cumsum()])['Car_Miles'].diff()
   .fillna(df[m].groupby('Plate')['Car_Miles'].diff()
                .fillna(df['Car_Miles']), downcast='infer')
)
```

Output (Make/Type columns removed for clarity):

```
      Plate  Car_Miles  Tire_Miles   Change Corrected_Change  Calculated_Tire_Miles
0   ABC-123        387         387      Yes              Yes                    387
1   ABC-123      15698       15311       No               No                  15311
2   ABC-123      25083        9385       No               No                   9385
3   ABC-123      37229       36842      Yes              Yes                  36842
4   ABC-123      50971       13742       No               No                  13742
5   ABC-123      85445       48216  Unknown              Yes                  48216
6   ABC-123     105870       20425       No               No                  20425
7   ABC-123     120454       14584       No               No                  14584
8   ABC-123     135878       50433  Unknown              Yes                  50433
9   DEF-456        507         507      Yes              Yes                    507
10  DEF-456      18796       18289       No               No                  18289
11  DEF-456      22879       22372  Unknown              Yes                  22372
12  DEF-456      38674       15795  Unknown               No                  15795
13  DEF-456      48678       25799  Unknown              Yes                  25799
14  DEF-456      55879        7201       No               No                   7201
15  DEF-456      65321       16643      Yes              Yes                  16643
16  DEF-456      78526       13205       No               No                  13205
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is an interesting method! I was expecting an if-else statement or a for loop but this is much a more straightforward one-liner solution.

Comment: `np.where` is the vectorized equivalent of a if/else. You could do it with a python if/else and `apply`, but this would be much slower.